# Output unique taxonomy terms of posts inside a loop

Tags: custom-taxonomy, theme-development

I'm trying to dynamically populate a dropdown list of taxonomy terms (`state` is the taxonomy used) of a custom post type (`product`) on a search form.

I can dynamically build the dropdown on it's own, but I'm trying to set it up so that if multiple `product`s are tagged with the same `state` the `state` term will only appear once on the dropdown.

My code:

```
$state_tax_args = array(
    'post_type' =>  'products',
    'orderby'   =>  'name',
    'order'     =>  'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product-line',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $pl_slug  //assigned at page start
        ),
    ),
);

$state_tax_query = new WP_Query( $state_tax_args );
$i=0;
if ( $state_tax_query->have_posts()) {
  $states = array();
  while ( $state_tax_query->have_posts()){ $state_tax_query->the_post();
    $state_terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'state', array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all') );
    foreach($state_terms as $st){
        $term = get_term( $st );
        $states[$i] = $term->slug ;
        $i++;
    }   // end foreach
  } //  end while

  $state_results = array_unique($states);
  print_r($state_results);

} // end if
wp_reset_query();
```

For testing purposes, I'm just printing the array before actually implementing the dropdown build, but right now all that's being output is `Array ( [0] => )`.

Edit: To clarify a few things...

The data hierarchy on my site is as follows:

I have a custom post type of `products` that has three custom taxonomies attached to it: `product-line`, `state`, and `carrier` (insurance stuff, yay!).  When I originally query the posts, I'm querying them by `product-line`, because the `product-line` term pages are where my search form lives.

Once I've queried the posts by `product-line`, I pull out their other two taxonomy terms (`state` and `carrier`) to dynamically create a dropdown for each so that if a `carrier` doesn't offer a `product` in that `product-line`, the `carrier` doesn't appear on the dropdown (and the same for `state`). Then, when a user searches for a `product`, the variables are passed (`state` and `carrier` from the form itself, and `product-line` from the page the search is executed from), the form is processed to build a query and return the results via AJAX.

Again, building the dropdowns works, but it outputs each term of `carrier` and `state` as many times as it appears on a `product` - I'm trying to make it output unique values, thus my confusion at the current `Array ( [0] => )` output.

Comment: `tax_query` should be an array of an array

Comment: @PieterGoosen edited question with suggested change, but still get the same output.

Comment: Hint: Reread the first line of your question and then check the values in your `tax_query` ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Edited with clarification of data heirarchy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out!

```
$state_tax_args = array(
    'post_type' =>  'products',
    'orderby'   =>  'name',
    'order'     =>  'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product-line',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $pl_slug // provided at page load
        ),
    ),
);

$state_tax_query = new WP_Query( $state_tax_args );
// counter to build array
$i=0;

if ( $state_tax_query->have_posts()) {

  $state_term_list='<select class="form-control" id="inputStateSelect" placeholder="State" name="stateSelect">';
  $state_term_list.='<option value="">...</option>';

  $states = array();

  while ( $state_tax_query->have_posts()){ $state_tax_query->the_post();
    $state_terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'state', $args = array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all'));
    foreach($state_terms as $state_term){
        $states[$i] = $state_term->name;
        $i++;
    } //  end foreach
  } //  end while

  //  kill the dupes
  $state_results = array_unique($states);

  //  alphebatize
  asort($state_results);

  //  build option list
  foreach($state_results as $state_result){
    $state_term_list.='<option value="' . $state_result . '">' . $state_result . '</option>';
  }

  $state_term_list.='</select>';

  echo $state_term_list;

} // end if
wp_reset_query();
```

That said, if I'm doing this just bonkers inefficiently, I'm always open to suggestions :)

Comment: You can eliminate the call to `array_unique()` and the need for the `$i` iterator by using `$states[$state_term->term_id] = $state_term->name;` instead. `term_id` should be unique and PHP will not allow duplicate keys in the array. +1 for solving your own problem.